# How to pass a background process to the foreground in C

Tags: c

I have to implement a function (Shell) that converts the background process identifier in a process pid in the foreground (waiting for it to finish).

I have this code:

```
if (sscanf(args[1], "%d", &pid_leido) == 1) { //read the pid 
            pid = (pid_t)pid_leido;

            if ((lp=getPid(lp, pid)) == NULL)
                printf("Proccess %s not found\n", args[1]);
            else { //if exists process with this pid 
                      (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) // i wait?¿?¿ 
                    perror(" wait4"); 
            }
```

Thanks ...

Comment: Any reason you're coding this by hand rather than using `fg`? I assume your target platform is some Unix?

Comment: You need to do that in C or in Bash/other shell?

Comment: please be more objective for what you want with this code

Comment: We need to implement a shell in c to the university

Comment: Then you also have a function to send a process to background. Record there a mapping between its job id and it's pid. In this function you only need to signal said process with the specific signal :)

Comment: Take a look at this explanation about foreground and background process. [Foreground and Background][1] Maybe this could help you. I think you will need to find a way to get the [job data structure][2] from your process ID, and use put_job_in_foreground function. 


  [1]: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html
  [2]: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_24.html#SEC420

Comment: You could always look into a shell source code and see how they do it, no need to be Bash whatsoever, just one that does this properly. The author of this shell might be a fellow of yours http://task3.cc/51/a-simple-tiny-unix-shell-written-in-c-language-opensource/